# Printing a pattern of *s to a .txt file in Python

Tags: python

I'm working on a project for class where the program I create should write a series of *s based on the input number of rows and columns (for example, 5 rows and 8 columns). I've gotten the pattern to print out in the console using

```
rows = int(input('Enter the number of rows: '))
cols = int(input('Enter the number of columns: '))
    
for row in range(rows, 0, -1):
    for col in range(0, cols):
        print('*', end = '')
    print()
```

but that doesn't seem to translate to using .write() or .writelines().

When I tried

```
boxPattern.write('*', end ='')
```

I got an error "write() does not take keyword arguments. I've tried a few different things including swapping out "end = ''" for '\n' to try to make the program create a new line and using .writelines() instead of .write() but it still doesn't do what I need it to do.

At this point, I've been trying to work this out on my own for about a week and I am at a loss. It's likely to be something simple, but I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Did you try reading the documentation for `.write`? What problem are you trying to solve by including the `end = ''`? *Does that problem actually exist*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something that looks like this:

```
>>> rows = 5
>>> columns = 5
>>> with open('stars.txt', 'w') as f:
...     for row in range(rows):
...             f.write('*' * columns + '\n')
```

The *write()* function does not support any keywords so you cannot specify the *end keyword*, but you can manually add *\n* to your string. You can look more into the documentation of the *os.write()* method and other I/O operations here: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects. Note that the * (mutiply operator) used with a string *x* and a number *n* will create a new string by concatenating *n* times the string *x*.